# Subequation Numbering and placement arrangements

Tags: equations, arrays, subequations

```
    \begin{subequations}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % or some other suitable value
\begin{flalign}
{}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M} &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      {}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ii} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & {}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 &{}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{s}}_{ii} \, 
   \end{bmatrix}, \label{fsi_mass_mat}\\
\mathbf{C} &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ii} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ic} & 0 \\
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ci} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{s}}_{ii} \,
   \end{bmatrix},\label{fsi_diffusion_mat} \\
\mathbf{G} &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{bmatrix}, \label{fsi_divergence_mat} \\
\mathbf{q(u)} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      0 \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{s}}_{c}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s}) \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s})
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_internal_force_vec_str}\\
\mathbf{N} &\equiv
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_convection_vec} \\
\mathbf{g} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i}  \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_external_force_vec} \\
\mathbf{a} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_accl_vec} \\
\mathbf{v} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_vel_vec} \\
\mathbf{u} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \ast \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{s}}_{i}
   \end{Bmatrix}, \label{fsi_disp_vec}\\
 \mathbf{p} &\equiv  \mathbf{p}^{\mathrm f}, \label{fsi_pressure_vec}\\
{}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm {fs}}_{cc} &\equiv {}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm {f}}_{cc}+{}_{\mathrm{L}}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm {s}}_{cc}, \label{FSI_mass_mat_coupled}
\end{flalign}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]

Hi members and @Mico :
Actually, I am looking for the type of numbering and arrangement of subequations as shown in the attached Figure. At present, I get the numbering as (4.45a),  (4.45b), (4.45c), (4.45d), (4.45e)...etc, shown in Top Figure. Eq.(4.45j) and (4.45k) runs outside the page. I want to change the numbering style only for this set of subequations like (4.45 a-k), as shown in the below figure (Last). Thank you.
[image]

Comment: It is easy to emulate this numbering, but you will  lose cross-referencing to individual subequations.

Comment: @Bernard, Please let me know how to do. I am desperately looking it. I need to cross-refer eq.(4.45i), however I will write the eqn number while cross-referring  eq.(4.45i). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bernard has pointed out in a comment, (a) your numbering system can be achieved without making use of a `subequations` environment and (b) one will necessarily lose the ability to cross-reference individual subequations.

For the following screenshot, I use a a single `align` environment, `\notag` directives for rows 1, 2, and 3, and a `\tag` directive to customize the appearance of the equation "number" in the final row. The main change, relative to the code you posted, is that I've replaced 7 of the 10 end-of-row `\\` (line-break) instructions with `\quad`. In addition, I removed the 11 existing `\label` statements since you don't want to output individual subequation numbers.

[image]

Speaking for myself, I cannot see a valid reason for maintaining that the full group of equations consists of 11 separate subequations if you're not also willing to make it easy for your readers to identify *which* subequation might, e.g., correspond to the letter "i", i.e., constitute the 9th subequation. It would be *much better* for your readers if you used a single `gather` environment and a single equation number for all 11 equations. If you really need to cross-reference one of the subequations, you'd just write something like "`... as can be seen in the expression for $\mathbf{g}$ in equation \eqref{<use the appropriate label>}, ...`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
% handy shortcut macro:
\newcommand\LMmat[1][]{{}_{\mathrm{L}\mkern-2mu}^{}\mathbf{M}^{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}\setcounter{equation}{44} % just for this example

\begingroup % localize scope of the following instruction
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % or some other suitable value
\begin{align}
\refstepcounter{equation}
\LMmat &\equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \LMmat[f]_{ii} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & \LMmat[fs]_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \LMmat[s]_{ii} \, 
   \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{C} \equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ii} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ic} & 0 \\
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ci} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{s}}_{ii} \,
   \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{G} \equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{bmatrix},  \notag\\
\mathbf{q(u)} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      0 \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{s}}_{c}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s}) \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s})
   \end{Bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{N} \equiv
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{Bmatrix},  \quad
\mathbf{g} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i}  \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix},  \notag \\
\mathbf{a} &\equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix},  \quad
\mathbf{v} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{u} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \ast \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i}
   \end{Bmatrix}, \notag\\
 \mathbf{p} &\equiv  \mathbf{p}^{\mathrm f}, \quad
\LMmat[fs]_{cc} \equiv \LMmat[f]_{cc} + \LMmat[s]_{cc}\,. 
\tag{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}a--k}
\label{eq:11subequations}
\end{align}
\endgroup

\noindent
A cross-reference to equations \eqref{eq:11subequations}.

%%%%%
\medskip\hrule\medskip

\begingroup % localize scope of the following instruction
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % or some other suitable value
\begin{gather}
\LMmat \equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \LMmat[f]_{ii} & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & \LMmat[fs]_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \LMmat[s]_{ii} \, 
   \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{C} \equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ii} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ic} & 0 \\
      \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{ci} & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{f}}_{cc} & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & \mathbf{C}^{\mathrm{s}}_{ii} \,
   \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{G} \equiv 
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{G}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{bmatrix},  \notag \\
\mathbf{q(u)} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      0 \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{s}}_{c}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s}) \\
      \mathbf{q}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{s})
   \end{Bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{N} \equiv
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{N}^{\mathrm{f}}_{c} \\
      0 
   \end{Bmatrix},  \quad
\mathbf{g} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i}  \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{g}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix},  \notag  \\
\mathbf{a} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix},  \quad
\mathbf{v} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{f}}_{i} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{v}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i} 
   \end{Bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{u} \equiv 
   \begin{Bmatrix}
      \ast \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{c} \\
      \mathbf{u}^{\mathrm{fs}}_{i}
   \end{Bmatrix}, \notag  \\
\mathbf{p} \equiv  \mathbf{p}^{\mathrm f}, \quad
\LMmat[fs]_{cc} \equiv \LMmat[f]_{cc} + \LMmat[s]_{cc}\,. 
\label{eq:11equationsgathered}
\end{gather}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico- Again Thank You Very Much. I will use the first code mentioned here by you.

Comment: @Mico- You really understood what I wanted. Thank you, sincerely, Prakash.